# How much influence does it take to level up?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

How much influence does it take per driver level in forza horizon 4? (As in, the level next to your name)

Is this linear or does the amount needed vary at different levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, at player level 150, it has taken a static 15,000 influence per level. I suspect this could increase after hitting level 200 and getting 1 star, where your level resets to level 1.

I received several pop up notifications in game that stated my total influence, which was always a multiple of 15,000. At level 101, the notification showed 1,500,000 total influence earned.

**update** I have since passed level 200, gaining the 1 star icon next to my name. It does seem to take more influence per level now, though I haven't been able to determine the exact amount yet.

Comment: Seems to be about 25,000 to 30,000 per level with 1 star